# Overlay image with transparent space in css

Tags: html, css, image

It's possible do like the image below in CSS 
overlay an 360 Panorama, with a empty transparent space, responsive and keeping the proportions

I tried creating 4 divs and using this css

```
<div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>

#frame  div:nth-child(1) {
    z-index:10;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#frame  div:nth-child(2) {
    z-index:10;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#frame  div:nth-child(3) {
    z-index:10;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0;
}
#frame  div:nth-child(4) {
    z-index:10;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Is it a question? Yes it's possible. Have you tried something to make it so far?

Comment: @KoshVery yes its a question, so far i make this with 4 divs, using % and opacity but when i change screen do not keep the proportion 16:9

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to place the image twice. 1 time as the transparent border and the second time centered and overflowing - and hide the overflowing part

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6hwkyL3b/27/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="trans-cont">
  <img class="trans-img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  <div class="center">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.trans-cont{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #454545;
  width: 40%;
}

.trans-img{
   opacity: 0.3;
   width: 100%;
}

.center{
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.center img{
  width: 125%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12.5%;
  left: -12.5%;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use the image once and hide it with divs as a border

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6hwkyL3b/34/)

Comment: @ltay gal The problem is i want to do this with a 360 pano, not a image

Comment: @Tidytrax the problem is that's not what you asked. Moreover you didn't show us anything you tried yourself. I suggest you accept that answer, as it answers the question written,then, open a new question in which you'll provide some code that you wrote, and we'll try to help solving the problem you're facing.

Comment: Ok sorry if i didn't explain so good, but you are here for the votes or to help? i did say didn't solve my problem, you can try undestand what it is and help, or just want some votes!

Comment: @Tidytrax seriously!?!? I gave you 2 solutions that works, then you commented that you have a problem that completely changes the question. here in stackoverflow we show what we already tried before asking for help. You didn't provide anything. We don't work for you, don't be rude. I'm not looking for votes, I'm looking to keep the order, and once a question is being answered you don't change it.

Comment: Ok man, like you need votes, i don't think you work for me, and i didn't was hude.

Answer (score -2):

Please try below:

HTML:

---

```
   <div class="container">
     <img src="imgSrc" alt="imgName" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="content">
     </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

---

```
.container {
       position: relative;
       max-width: 100%;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .container img {vertical-align: middle;}

   .container .content{
     position: absolute;
     top: 25%;
     left: 20%;
     width: 60%;
     height: 40%;
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 9rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

Comment: Usage of box-shadow for such transparencies is not modern; CSS3 'opacity' attribute should be used